# Best switch type to turn off the mains voltage to electronics

Tags: switches, mains, safety

Basically I am making a reflow plate, that requires mains voltage for the heating plate. I have a basic knowledge of mains voltage and am just trying to make the product as safe as possible, by adding fuses, grounding any metal parts, having isolation between high voltage and low voltage.

But I am not sure if it matters what type of switch I use for turning the device on and off. Can I use any switch meant for any electronics or is there a type of switch used for mains that would be better/ safer.

Thanks in advance,
Dean.

Comment: Hi Dean, What's the heater's voltage and wattage?

Comment: You might want to add an illuminated indicator for when the device is powered on. That way, you can see if it's been left on at the end of the day. You can get illuminated rocker switches which incorporate an indicator. Places like RS Components and Farnell are reputable suppliers in the UK.

Comment: Hi vu2an, the heaters voltage is mains so around 220-240vac

Comment: Good idea Andrew, will do thanks for the info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as the switch is specified for 240V AC use and the contact current rating is greater than that drawn by the plate it shouldn't matter what switch you use.
Since you are in the UK make sure it has British Standard (BS) marking. Try to make sure it's a genuine part from a reputable manufacturer and supplier. Double pole is much better than single, completely isolating the plate from the mains no matter which way the power is connected (mistakes do happen, line and neutral do get reversed).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use any switch.

The switch must have safety approvals your electrical code requires for mains voltage.

In addition, the switch must be rated for local mains voltage with some margin , it must be rated to handle the rated current, and it must be rated to handle any inrush current as the heater will draw a surge of current when it is cold and switch is turned on.

In addition to just the voltage and current, the switch must be rated to handle the switched power. A switch might be rated for 250VAC and 10A, but the ratings may not apply simultaneously and you can't assume you can switch a 250VAC and 10A load, or 2500W.

The switch must also handle your intended type of load, inductive, capacitive or resistive. Fortunately heaters are resistive but can still take a surge of current when cold.

So, pick a switch and read the datasheet to figure out if it is suitable or not.

As mentioned already, it is typically safer to use a dual pole switch to disconnect both live and neutral, instead of just one of them (live, but while UK has polarized plugs, don't assume they are always wired properly with 100% guarantee).

Comment: great thank you for your detail response. I will have a look into the dual pole switches at uk rated mains, thank you.

Comment: The inrush current shouldn't be such a problem with a heating plate. Whilst tungsten light bulbs have a much lower resistance when cold than when hot, the elements in heating plates tend to be made from resistance wire with a much lower temperature coefficients. Also the temperature difference between cold and hot is less. For example tungsten 4.5 x 10E-3, Nichrome (a very common heating wire) 0.40 x 10E-3 ten times less.